# jQuery effect doesn't work on the first button click, But from the second click onward it does

Tags: jquery, css

I'm trying to open a link menu with some jQuery effects. Unfortunately when I click the first time, the menu opens but without any effects. However, after the second click the effects start working. Why and how can I solve that?

CSS File

```
.MenuWrapper {
z-index: 100;
display: inline-table;
position: fixed;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
top: 0;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
text-align: center;
visibility: hidden;
}
```

Script file

```
$('.openMenu').click(function () {
    $(".MenuWrapper").css("visibility", "visible").fadeIn(500);
    $(".MenuText").fadeIn(500);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is the opacity, for fadeIn to work try setting the initial opacity as `0`

```js
$('.openMenu').click(function() {
  $(".MenuWrapper").css("visibility", "visible").fadeTo(500, 1);
  $(".MenuText").fadeIn(500);
});

$('.MenuWrapper a').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(".MenuWrapper").fadeTo(500, 0, function() {
    $(this).css("visibility", "hidden")
  });
});
```

```css
.MenuWrapper {
  z-index: 100;
  display: inline-table;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  text-align: center;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="openMenu">Open</button>
<div class="MenuWrapper">
  This is the menu content
  <a class="close" href="">Close</a>
</div>
```

Comment: I've changed the opcacity to 0 as you suggested but that didn't help. The Menu opened in a transparent mode.... which means the opacity remained 0.

Comment: @Gloria I have updated with a demo.. can you try that

Comment: @Gloria also edit [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/26yLbojy/1/) to recreate your problem

Comment: Your code works perfectly well in your case.... But that didn't solve my problem unfortunately.

Comment: @Gloria that mean there are some missing elements... can you create a demo of your problem in the above fiddle

Comment: Now it works but is your script compatible with older browsers??? I'm affraid that the menu will not show at all since the opacity is set to 0 from the start.

Answer (score 1):

```js
$('.openMenu').click(function () {
    $(".MenuWrapper").fadeIn(500);
    $(".MenuText").fadeIn(500);
});
```

```css
.MenuWrapper {
z-index: 100;
display: inline-table;
position: fixed;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
top: 0;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
text-align: center;
display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="openMenu">Open</button>
<div class="MenuWrapper">
  This is the menu content
  <a class="close" href="">Close</a>
</div>
```

Try with display instead of visibility attribute